# How to stop annoying feature to remove using statements on save in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I cannot find any setting to stop this madness, any suggestions?

All the unused using statements are removed when saving, not so great when converting a bunch of projects and manually updating multiple files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have Code Cleanup configured to run on Save.  You can configure this it Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Cleanup.

[image: Tools/Options configuration for Code Cleanup]

Alternatively, you can configure which tasks Code Cleanup performs and set it to not remove the using statements.  You can find this under Analyze -> Code Cleanup -> Configure Code Cleanup, or on the lower editor margin in a button with a sparkling broom symbol.

[image: Configure Code Cleanup dialog]

Comment: Hi, I'm having this issue as well. I've tried those solutions but the using are still being removed on save. I've also closed and reopened VS after adjusting the settings and same problem occurs.